# Error while creating NER model on Stanford NER

Tags: stanford-nlp

While I was creating a NER model, I got an error message as below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Got NaN for prob in CRFLogConditionalObjectiveFunction.calculate() - this may well indicate numeric underflow due to overly long documents.
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFLogConditionalObjectiveFunction.calculate(CRFLogConditionalObjectiveFunction.java:427)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.optimization.AbstractCachingDiffFunction.ensure(AbstractCachingDiffFunction.java:140)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.optimization.AbstractCachingDiffFunction.valueAt(AbstractCachingDiffFunction.java:145)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.optimization.QNMinimizer.lineSearchMinPack(QNMinimizer.java:1460)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.optimization.QNMinimizer.minimize(QNMinimizer.java:1008)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.optimization.QNMinimizer.minimize(QNMinimizer.java:857)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.optimization.QNMinimizer.minimize(QNMinimizer.java:851)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.optimization.QNMinimizer.minimize(QNMinimizer.java:93)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier.trainWeights(CRFClassifier.java:1919)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier.train(CRFClassifier.java:1726)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.train(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:758)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.train(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:746)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier.main(CRFClassifier.java:3034)
```

To create the NER, I simply used the Java code from Stanford NER website [here].
[1](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.html)

The Java code was:

`java -cp stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -prop 06012017_training.prop`

Also, the TSV file used to create NER was 35.369MB.
I am trying to create only one tag with the title "SYS".

How do I overcome this Error and successfully create an NER model?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: @StanfordNLPHelp

Comment: Just to answer my own question, I did not get any error when I separated all punctuations then removed them.
Also, when using the code to tokenize, it is good to go!
java -cp stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBTokenizer jane-austen-emma-ch1.txt > jane-austen-emma-ch1.tok